# Android EditText highlight multiple words

Tags: android, android-edittext, cpu-word, highlight

Thats my current code:

```js
    public void markWords(String str) {
        str = str.replace("\n", " <br>");
        int spamLength = 20;
        String colorSpam = "#ED9E15";
        String colorBad = "red";
        int i = 0;

        for(String word : str.split(" ")) {
            if(word.length() > spamLength) {
                str = str.replace(word, "<font color='"+colorSpam+"'>"+word+"</font>");
                i++;
            }
        }

        for(String bad : blacklist) {
            if (!bad.startsWith("#") && str.toLowerCase().contains(bad.toLowerCase())) {
                for (String word : str.split(" ")) {
                    if (word.toLowerCase().contains(bad.toLowerCase())) {
                        String rightWord = getRightCased(word, bad);
                        if (word.length() > spamLength) {
                            str = str.replace(rightWord, "</font><font color='"+colorBad+"'>" + rightWord + "</font><font color='"+colorSpam+"'>");
                        } else {
                            str = str.replace(rightWord, "<font color='"+colorBad+"'>" + rightWord + "</font><font color='black'></font>");
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(str), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        String gefunden = "Es wurden " + i + " Wörter gefunden.";
        if(i == 1) {
            gefunden = "Es wurde " + i + " Wort gefunden.";
        }
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), gefunden, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            msg.show();
    }

    public String getRightCased(String str, String bad) {
        String string = str;

        for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(!string.toLowerCase().startsWith(bad.toLowerCase())) {
                string = string.substring(1);
            }
        }
        for(int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if(!string.toLowerCase().endsWith(bad.toLowerCase())) {
                string = string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return string;
    }
```

It works the first time, but crashes when the text contains a html tag or if some blank spaces gets added to the text and then highlight the words again ... How can i highlight multiple words without using html tags?

Answer (score 0):

The way to actually make text appear styled in a TextView (or EditText) is to create Spans, such as ColorSpannable.  That's what HTML.fromHtml() does for you.  Using HTML is the easiest way, but as you pointed out quickly has issues if you try to do it on html text or do it repeatedly.  If you roll your own span creation by hand it will be a pain in the neck, but you'd avoid those problems by never using HTML.